Aiogram 3.x. Как передать в send_invoice id загруженного фото?
Метод send_invoice принимает только "photo_url", но мне нужно передать фото, которое было загружено через photo = message.photo[-1].file_id.

Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой, как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
